# Python Exceptions (Documentation Example)

Tags: python, class, exception

Below is an example piece of code from the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) dealing with exception handling and classes. I am working to understand both of these, and my background is in Java, so I am used to strongly typed classes and variables. Would someone please explain in detail what is going on here?

```
class B:
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(C):
    pass

for c in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise c()
    except D:
        print "D"
    except C:
        print "C"
    except B:
        print "B"
```

Are the first six lines actually creating instances of B, C, and D or just creating a class type. If they are just class types, I assume they are instated in `for c in [B, C, D]:`. How can instances of classes C and D be instantiated without parameters? Then what is going on with the exception stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first six lines create classes.  I like to think of them as definitions of instances that will later be created.  Using `for c in [B, C, D]:` does *not* instantiate anything; it just assigns `c` to each of `B`, `C`, and `D` which are still just classes.  For the first iteration, `c` is the same thing as `B`.  Therefore, when you say `raise c()`, `c()` makes an instance of `B` and raises it as an exception.  That exception is caught in the `except B:` block and causes the `print "B"` line to execute.  For the next iteration, `c` is assigned to the next value in `[B, C, D]`: `C`.  Now, `raise c()` makes an instance of `C` and raises it as an exception.  That exception is caught in the `except C:` block and the `print "C"` line is executed.  The same thing happens with `D`.

Answer (score 1):

The first six lines define the classes. They are instantiated without parameters because e.g. `class C(B):` means that class `C` *inherits* from `B`, not that instantiation of `C` requires passing an argument. This is explained in the [documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html).

Each time through the loop, the interpreter will raise an error of the given class. It will print whatever type of exception class is raised, with `B` for `B` and so on. The output, as you see when you run that code, is `B`, then `C`, then `D`, because those are the classes of exception that were raised, in that order, as you see in `[B, C, D]` over which the loop iterated.

Answer (score 0):

The first six lines are creating the class types.

Since everything in python can be assigned to a variable, this includes functions, classes (not just instantiated objects of that class) `for c in [B, C, D]:` is doing.

Lastly what the exceptions are doing first in the `try:` it tries to raise an exception of type `c` by creating an instance of it. Thus it first raises an exception of type B then type C then type D.

The `except`s are there to catch those exceptions, for each type. In python 2 any object can be raised as an exception, this is different from python 3 where all exceptions that are raised must derive from type BaseException